# Is it possilbe to add notes on folders or files?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I am working on Linux 18.04, I want to write a note for some folders ¿are there any tools for doing it? I was thinking over one option in the contextual menu ¿is it posible?

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure if there is such a thing but I used to have a text file at the top of the folder with a description of the folder or its content. 
GL

Comment: Indeed, there is no native feature for this in nautilus nor in other file managers that I know of. Having a text file such as e.g. `!folderinfo` (so it appears on top) is a (albeit perhaps primitive) possibility to maintain comments.